# BLE out of range detection for UI update

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am unable to figure out a way to detect BLE device out of range to update UI in discovered state**(and not in connected state-- in which case we can easily update with didDisconnect callback).**

Following workarounds seems to drain up the battery:
 1. Enable CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey and keep checking RSSI
 2. Have a timer at scan time, after discovery on timeout keep checking if the device objects created is not in connected state and discovery time is more the timeout then stop and start scan again.
Any other better option would help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoreBluetooth: detect device out of range/ connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885303/corebluetooth-detect-device-out-of-range-connection-timeout)

Comment: Its not related to connection timeout. Its just after discovery. In discovered state only.

Comment: The link provides valid answers to both situations. You may want to read it again.